# Are boomalopes possible? aka a species that produces a flammable fuel?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, fuels, environment

[image]

I was inspired by this creature in a game called rimworld  the creature when killed explodes and leaves a fireball ,and a corpse , when it does.   The sacks on it contain a liquid  that can be used as fuel if you milk the animal. I was wondering is such a creature possible? the lore of rimworld says this creature was genetically engineered but my creature evolved over time. What type of environment that would allow this monstrosity to evolve and would you be able to milk it?

Comment: Farts are extremely flammable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ambergris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambergris) is an oily substance created in the digestive system of sperm whales, possibly to aid in passing hard objects in their food. It is apparently [flammable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-twcaxpqfoI) though more in the way candle wax is flammable as opposed to being explosive.

It is not uncommon for naturally evolving creatures to produce useful substances. [Formic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formic_acid) gets it's name from ants that produce it and [Bombardier beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle) produce Hydrogen Peroxide to defend themselves.

Combining flammable oils, exothermic reactions and the ability to spray liquids in one creature seems like something nature could feasibly come up with. The biggest issue would be making it immune to it's own fire, but depending on what you need the critter for, maybe it has a different use besides combat.

Comment: the critter explodes when it dies  and  I just want it for its milk being fuel practically. I dont want it for combat

Answer (score 1):

A different kind of lactation.

Fat can be rendered into an oil, which can be rather flammable, and mammals have a rather handy form of fat storage and processing and fluid dispensation already. I'm not entirely sure what exact conditions would lead to a mammal evolving to lactate a highly calorie-dense oil-like form of liquid fat instead of milk, like perhaps dryer conditions requiring feeding their young to require using less water, but if they did then you basically have an animal that produces and stores within itself an easily accessible and harvestable form of fuel. Heck, the animal might just explode into a fireball under the right conditions, like storing the oil in excess and suffering the strike of lightning or some other form of high energy introduction event.